# How to send email in my iOS Application . I have my own designed Contact us Page View 

Tags: iphone, ios

How to send email in my iOS Application . I have my own designed Contact us Page View .
in my Contact us Page view ,  i have 2 text fields , 1 text view  and 1 Ui Button . After entering the name , email address , message  when the user click the send button , the mail have to send to the admin.

How to do this in ioS .... Please any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the experience directly from the phone is usually like this:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString: @"mailto:foo@example.com?subject=Feedback&body=Hello"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

If you don't want that interface to show up then you'll have to have the email functionality in a server and you simply make an HTTP call to your server with the data you need to be sent.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the "MailComposer" Sample code that Apple provides.  They use `MFMailComposeViewController`.  This method allows you to stay in the app while composing the message and lets you setup a lot of the content in the message programatically.

Answer (score 2):

check this out http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

```
NSString *stringURL = @"mailto:test@example.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

have that run when the user taps the send button

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
let to = "email@email.com"
let subject = "Subject text"
//let body = "body text"
//let cc = "cc@email.com"
//let bcc = "bcc@email.com"

let address = "mailto:\(to)?subject=\(subject)"
// OR if you want to use other parameters
//let address = "mailto:\(to)?subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)&cc=\(cc)&bcc=\(bcc)"

// escape the URL
let urlAddressEscaped = address.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)

let url = URL(string: urlAddressEscaped!)!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Create Contacts us API from Your Server then design a UIView with your Parameters to be sent to the server